# ¿Cómo bloquear la desinstalación y/o borrado de datos al usuario de mi aplicación android?

Tags: android

Estoy desarrollando una app android y me gustaría que el usuario no pudiera desinstalar la aplicación o borrar los datos de la aplicación en el dispositivo.

Comment: Eso me suena muy peligroso. ¿Por qué el usuario no podría desinstalar una app que instaló?

Comment: Es una app de uso privado, no público, y al desinstalar o borrar los datos de la app podrían haber pérdidas de información, ya que esta app se sincroniza con una base de datos externa

Comment: Creo que tu problema es cómo evitar que se pierda la información al desinstalar la aplicación del dispositivo y sincronizarlo con la fuente de datos externa. No deberías restringir a los usuarios de una app a que no puedan desinstalarla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El bloquear la desinstalación no es posible es parte de las caracteristicas que ofrece el sistema operativo.

En cuanto al cache de la aplicación tampoco es posible no permitir el borrado de datos.

Ambas cosas no es posible y no se debería restringir al usuario.

Lo que deseas seguramente es lo que se tiene en una aplicación del sistema, las cuales son preinstaladas y se encuentran en la partición del sistema en la cual los usuarios regularmente no se puede acceder.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración